# Vim - Prevent cursor from moving when yanking to a mark

Tags: vim, copy-paste

I typically use marks to cut/paste in Vim.

To yank the text between lines 4 and 12, I do the following:

1. move cursor to line 4
2. type `mx` to place a mark named x
3. move cursor to line 12
4. type `y'x` to yank the text between lines 4 and 12

After doing this, the cursor moves back to line #4.

Is there a way to make the cursor stay where it is (without moving back to the mark)?

If anybody has a better ways to do the same thing, that would be great, too...

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:**

I used FDinoff's answer to create a mapping that is making me one happy camper:

```
nnoremap YY y'x<C-O>
```

This yanks from the cursor to the mark named x, then returns the cursor to where it was.

This has already saved me **tons** of time.  Thanks again!

Comment: I don’t see an obvious way to do this in the docs, but would it be enough to hit Ctrl-O after the yank to jump back to line 12?

Comment: @andrewdotn - That's a great start (and probably a sufficient solution)... It will be especially useful after adding a mapping.  Thanks!  (feel free to make this an answer if you want some rep points).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you jump to line 4 is because you are using yank with a backwards motion.

```
                            *y* *yank*
["x]y{motion}       Yank {motion} text [into register x].  When no
            characters are to be yanked (e.g., "y0" in column 1),
            this is an error when 'cpoptions' includes the 'E'
            flag.
```

The motion in question is [`'x`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27) which is jump to mark x. The cursor is moved to the beginning of the yanked part which in this case is line 4 since you were yanking from line 12.

However things you could do.

1. Use a [range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%5brange%5d) for an ex command line mode yank. The range is `.` (current line) to `'x` (mark x). If the range is backwards with will ask you is you meant the other direction. This won't move your cursor. `:.,'xy`
2. Or you could use [`<C-o>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#CTRL-O) will will jump you back to the last place you jumped from. (which was mentioned in the comments.)
3. Or you could use [`']`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%27%5d) or `` `] ``. These commands will jump you the last character of the the last yanked text.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate both the explanation and the alternatives!

Comment: I don't think this is the 'reason', because most yank motions *don't* move the cursor. e.g. yj yl y}. I actually found this post while searching for a command that yanks *and* performs the motion, which is sometimes helpful for complicated motions like yf3/. I don't suppose you've found such a command?

Comment: @MichaelScheper The yank puts the cursor at the beginning of the yanked section. In all of your examples the cursor was already at the beginning of the yanked section. Off the top of my head no, I do not know how to put the cursor at the end of the yanked part.

Answer (score 3):

Jump back with: <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

For more help see:

```
:h ``
:h CTRL-O
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `y12G`?
This will yank from current position (line 4) to line 12.

Comment: That would work, but this workflow is generally used when you don't know how many lines you're going to yank.  I just used lines 4 and 12 to explain the scenario.  In real life 4 and 12 should be replaced with "_some random line number that I select by navigating around the file_".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to keep the cursor on line 4.

With the cursor on line 4 `V 12G y`.

Even `v`, I think all you are missing is [visual mode](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#Visual).

[These motions](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#object-select) also help.

Comment: The goal is actually to remain on line 12. Returning to line 4 is the default behavior.