# Retaining cursor position when yanking

Tags: vim, copy

I've never been comfortable with yank always moving the cursor to the start of the target string, that is, even when you are using yank with a backwards motion (such as `k` or `b`). So, is it possible to have the cursor always retain its position when yanking?

I couldn't find answers elsewhere, and had no luck with a simple function involving the CursorMoved event.

Comment: You could get some ideas from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975610/vim-prevent-cursor-from-moving-when-yanking-to-a-mark -- I am used to `\`\`` because it's fast to type but I don't know if it could work for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

add this to your ~/.vimrc:

```
vnoremap y mcy`c
```

now, in visual mode, y will:

1. mc - set mark c at cursor position
2. y - yank
3. `c - move cursor back to to mark c